# Start new R package development on github

Tags: r, github, rstudio, devtools

How do I create new repository on github using devtools in RStudio? I've tried to:

1. Create empty repository on github named "MyNewRPackage"
2. Started new project in RStudio using ssh connection to my git repository
3. Installed and loaded devtools

Then I thought I will use `create("MyNewRPackage")` to initialize directory structure and `README.md` file. But the package skeleton is created as subfolder of my project and I have `~/MyNewRPackage/MyNewRPackage/R`. But I need to create package skeleton in the root folder of my github repository.

What is the standard way to start new R package development on github using devtools and RStudio?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hope this helps someone:

1. Create empty repository on github (I will use name `rpackage` in this example)
2. Create package locally using devtools, `create("rpackage")` (this will create rpackage folder)
3. Create new project in RStudio (Create project from: Existing directory) and choose `rpackage` directory
4. In RStudio go to Tools/Shell... and type `git init`
5. Reopen the project (this will refresh the Git tab)
6. Start Git/More/Shell and type

   `git add *`

   `git commit -m "first commit"`

   `git remote add origin git@github.com:[username]/rpackage.git`

   `git push -u origin master`

Then you can refresh repository on `github`. Now you can close (or even delete) your local project and next time you can start a new project Project/New project/Version Control/Git

Comment: I would use `git push -u origin master --force`

Answer (score 3):

Now there's `setup()`, which creates the skeleton *inside* an existing directory. Together with [`hub`](https://github.com/github/hub), this becomes:

```
git init NewPackage
cd NewPackage
Rscript -e "devtools::setup()"
hub create
git add .
git commit -m "initial"
git push -u origin HEAD
```

Comment: Thanks!  I got a warning though.  Looks like `devtools::setup()` should be replaced by `usethis::create_package()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the path to your github repository in `create` instead of the package name:

```
create("/path/to/root/of/repository")
```

Then the normal git commands to add, commit and push to github:

```
git commit -a -m "initial commit" *
git push
```

Comment: If I try `create("/home/xxx/MyNewRpackage")` I get: `Error: Directory already exists`. That is true, because I've already started new project and pulled empty repository from github. Should I somehow reorder my steps?

Comment: Yes, `devtools:create` won't stomp on something that already exists.